# How to set nearby locations into a TableView retrieved from Firebase

Tags: swift, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, latitude-longitude

I am new to Swift 3 and I have a question that is about determining whether a coordinate is nearby or not, relative to the users location. After that I want to display the nearby location into a TableView.

This is my Firebase structure:

[image]

My class looks like this:

```
class UITableViewControllerForShop: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

These variables are global:

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Butikker")
var retrieveData = [String:AnyObject]()
var distanceInMeters: CLLocationDistance!
```

In my viewDidLoad function I execute this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
                let dictionary = snap.value as! [String: AnyObject]

                self.retrieveData = ["latitude": dictionary["Latitude"] as! Double as AnyObject, "longtitude": dictionary["Longtitude"] as! Double as AnyObject]
            }
        })
}
```

To check the users location and compare it with the Firebase location I execute this:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]

    print(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)

    //My location
    let myCoordinate = CLLocation(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)

    if self.retrieveData.isEmpty == false {
        let shopCoordinate = CLLocation(latitude: retrieveData["latitude"]! as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: retrieveData["longtitude"]! as! CLLocationDegrees)
        print(shopCoordinate.coordinate.latitude, shopCoordinate.coordinate.longitude)
        distanceInMeters = myCoordinate.distance(from: shopCoordinate)
        print(distanceInMeters)
    }
    //Distance
}
```

I initialize my tableview like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

    if distanceInMeters > 5000 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = retrieveData["latitude"] as! String
    }
    return cell
}
```

These are the problems I have:

1. I can't figure out how to check if my distance > 5000 after it is initialized inside locationManager function.
2. My dictionary retrieveData won't store more than 1 value per key which leads to a problem if I want to display a list of nearby items into a tableview.
3. It takes time to go through the for in loop, which makes everything more difficult to get.

Questions I want to have an answer on:

1.How to use distanceInMeters after it is initialized inside      locationManager function?

2.How to determine whether something is nearby or not and put into my TableView?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this I suggest you use a library that does exactly what you need: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc

I guess you could write this by yourself but it would take a lot of time since Firebase doesn't help you with any functions related to GeoLocation (if you compare it to Parse service (dead), which already included features to query for location by distance).